# How to create an inline review comment in github in the diff view using github actions

Tags: github, curl, github-actions, github-api, pull-request

I have been trying to use github actions to place a comment inline in the pull request diff. I have tried to follow this documentation: [review-comment-in-diff](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request) however nothing seemed to work as expected. The documentation seems to state that you can just use the property `position`, but other docs say you need `commit_id` and `path` for it to work [create-a-comment](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.2/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment). If I do not add `commit_id` or `path`, I get an error message that they are missing, if I add it I get a validation error. I will show both below. Note that the first error message also mentions missing `in_reply_to` and `line` which according to the documentation is not needed for creating a new comment using `position`.

```
- name: publish line comment curl
        if: contains(env.SCRIPT_OUTPUT, 'FAIL')
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          curl \
            -X POST \
            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
            https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}/comments \
            -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
            --data '{  "body": "blah blah" ,
                    "path": "SomeDir/SomeFile.json",
                    "position": 1
                    }'
```

> {
> "message": "Invalid request.\n\nNo subschema in "oneOf" matched.\n"commit_id" wasn't supplied.\n"in_reply_to" wasn't supplied.\n"position" is not a permitted key.\n"commit_id", "line" weren't supplied.",

```
--data '{  "body": "blah blah" ,
                    "path": "SomeDir/SomeFile.json",
                    "position": 1,
                    "commit_id": "${{ github.sha }}"
                    }'
```

> "message": "Validation Failed",
> "errors": [
> {
> "resource": "PullRequestReviewComment",
> "code": "custom",
> "field": "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid",
> "message": "pull_request_review_thread.end_commit_oid is not part of the pull request"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `github.event.pull_request.head.sha` instead of `github.sha` in order to get the latest commit. The error messages and documentation were quite cryptic so maybe this will help someone else. Also, it is required that you provide `path` and `commit_id` in addition to `position`. If you do all that you end up with a comment in the diff view (Files Changed Tab) and also a notification with the comment is posted in the main comment section of the pull request with a link to view it.